# How do you prevent a continuous webjob from restarting after an error occured?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a website with four continuous webjobs listening on different topics of a service bus.

If during the execution of one these webjobs, an error occurs and the process exits, how do I prevent the webjob to start up again (which in most cases would simply incur in the error again)?

I tried keeping a `disable.job` file in the root of each webjob folder, thinking that if I then ran the webjob manually it would override it, but instead it shuts down almost immediately after detecting that that file is present (I thought it would only check on an automatic restart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mechanism today to achieve that. If a continuous WebJob is not disabled, the WebJob engine will always try to restart if it crashes for any reason. That is what most users expect.

If you don't want that, one thing you could do is catch the exception in your WebJob, and simply do nothing (i.e. get in a Sleep loop). However, I would suggest getting to the bottom of the error, and seeing whether it can be avoided.

Comment: I do not have any errors at the moment. I just want to avoid the webjob to endlessly loop on an error indefinitely if one ever happens. Is there any way for a continuous webjob to write to the filesystem without triggering a restart? Or would I be able to create a triggered webjob that has no timeout (which would effectively be my goal?)

Comment: Would not recommend a triggered WebJob, as semantic is different. Yes, you can write to the file system without restart if you don't try to modify your own WebJob files. Not sure how that relates to the question though.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. What I would do is, when the webjob starts up, check for a file called first.run. If present, delete it and continue with the normal webjob task. If not present, that means that it's not the first webjob run, so write the disable.job file and stop. Maybe I could manipulate environment variables to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Environment variables would not work well as they would not persist if you set them. But the file idea might work. If you do this, you should write to the %TMP% folder, to make sure your marker file is not persisted across site restarts.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll keep that in mind. I have some other questions relative to filesystem changes detection in webjobs (I currently keep a little log file inside my webjob folder, which is restarting the webjob everytime I write something to it), should I open another question or maybe you have some documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Basically, Azure listens to file changes anywhere under your WebJobs folder, so you should not write to there. If you want to keep a persistent log, one good place is under `d:\home\data\SomeFolderYouPick`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see what I can come up with.